# How can I share my files from mobile device to PC through wireless router?

Tags: networking

I have a wireless router and my pc has ip : 192.168.1.101 and my htc desire mobile has ip: 192.168.1.102. But I am not able to ping my mobile from PC. I just want to access my files on mobile through pc. I have also downloaded some app from PlayStore but I am not able to ping my mobile though my pc and mobile are both on same network. Please ! help.

Comment: Ping is not necessary for file sharing to work, and many mobile phones have it disabled for various security reasons. What App did you download? Is it displaying an error code?

Comment: I am using Wireless File Transfer Lite. As it suggested, when i start this service, It provide me an url : XXXXXX. When I used this address from my browser, it doesn't work at all. I try to ping it from command prompt like ping XXXXXXX but I can't. How can I work on it?

Comment: Does it work the other way around (i.e. pinging your PC from the HTC Desire)? It might be a somehow restrictive firewall involved, e.g. on the router. Some routers also have a special settings to allow connected devices communicating with each other.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Android may not have a ping service as one of it's utilities, so trying to ping your device might not work.  Regardless, you should be able to navigate directly to your device's storage from your PC's file manager by running an Android app like [Samba](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funkyfresh.samba).

Comment: Funny. I can ping my Android devices. Even those with stock ROM (like my LG Optimus). And no, I didn't install anything specific for that.

Comment: Really?  None of mine respond to a ping - I was under the impression it had been left out, like a lot of other services.  Is yours rooted with BusyBox? It might be coming from that.

Comment: Let me test: The Optimus (ICS 4.0.3) is rooted, but no BusyBox installed manually (though TitaniumBackup might have done so). Same for the Milestone² (CM7.2 / GB 2.3.7, TiBu) and the Wildfire (CM9.1 / ICS 4.0.4, TiBu). My CSG2 (not rooted, JB 4.1.1) responds as well, as does the Phoenix (completely stock JB 4.1.1, nothing installed manually, as it's a "demonstration device"). So none of my devices does not respond to `ping`, whatever configuration they have, as long as they are connected to my WiFi.

Comment: I'll edit my answer then, thanks for the testing.

Comment: You are welcome, Logos! Was about time I made that sure (up to today, I didn't thoroughly test it -- but now I can say "I never had a device not supporting it"). There are two more devices I can check when they return, though...

Answer (score 0):

Ping is most basic network service provided by all modern devices. Non availability of ping service is rare and that's also the case of ping being turned off manually by users. So, its most likely that **your firewall on PC is blocking outbound traffic to the Android device in the network**.

Disable the firewall on PC temporarily and test. If you have firewall installed on Android device, disable it there too.

If firewall was the problem, allow all outbound traffic to all ports of Android device's IP (you may restrict to ports in use). If firewall was installed on Android device, do the same thing for inbound traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Try using AirDroid
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid 

This should help you to manage files on your android device through WiFi.